# Exact redirects -- what happens if I now add a custom domain?

Tags: redirect, read-the-docs, custom-domain

I wanted to check something before I break everything. It may be obvious to you, but I'm naturally cautious and wanted to see whether I'm OK to do what I'm thinking.

I currently have docs on RTD (and have had them there for 3 years). We have moved pages around as versions changed, so have a set of about a hundred exact redirects, something like this:

/en/stable/introduction/intro.html -> /en/stable/introduction/setup-guide.html

Now I have a custom domain and want to point everything with a canonical link over there.

What will happen to those redirects? Are they applied *first* so someone with a bookmark to `intro.html` is pointed to `setup-guide.html` over on project.readthedocs.io and *then* the redirect to myprojectname.com/docs/ applied?

That is, will this happen?

```
/en/stable/introduction/intro.html --> myprojectname.com/docs/en/stable/introduction/setup-guide.html
```

Thanks in advance?

I haven't tried this yet. I'm too scared I'll break the whole edifice and end world order.

Comment: Asked this on the Read the Docs issue tracker https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/9988

Comment: Thanks! I'll report back here on any answers.